# Heroku ignoring recent migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, heroku

I just ran `heroku rake db:migrate` and three of my most recent migrations are being ignored completely. I've pushed everything to Heroku and github but it's like Heroku doesn't think these even exist.

`git status` reveals nothing amiss, and my Github repo contains the migration files in the right place.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said it should work..

If you're completely stuck, you could always try pulling your production database from heroku, migrating on your local machine and then pushing the database back up to heroku?

At the very least you might be able to see what's going on in your database at least?

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/

Comment: I was finally able to perform the migration by selecting each one individually, i.e. `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=201102020192001...`. Strange!

Answer (score 4):

Running "heroku restart" from the command line sometimes fixes the issue too.